# Problems to enter or error, no bar graph, no ggplot2 and individual cores by groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graphics, bar-chart

You are trying to enter not all the bars of the bar graph as the standard errors, however, to calculate the errors separately and enter a geom_errorbar function or it is not being executed. How can I solve?

[image]

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)

dados4$VARIAVEIS = as.factor(dados4$VARIAVEIS)
dados4$PERIODO = as.factor(dados4$PERIODO)
dados4$GRUPOS  = as.factor(dados4$GRUPOS)

errors <- dados4 %>%
  group_by(VARIAVEIS:GRUPOS) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Resposta), 
            sd = sd(Resposta),
            sem = sd(Resposta)/sqrt(length(Resposta)))

gap3 <- aggregate(Resposta ~ VARIAVEIS + PERIODO + GRUPOS + errors, data=dados4, FUN=mean)

graf2=ggplot(gap3, aes(x = VARIAVEIS, y = Resposta, fill = factor(PERIODO))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") + facet_grid(~ GRUPOS) + theme(strip.text.x=element_text(size = 15)) +
  labs(title = "",
       x = "Variáveis",
       y = expression(paste('Comprimentos e Diâmetros'," ",'(',mu, m,')')),
       fill = "Períodos") +
theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 15),legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
      axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", hjust=1),
      axis.title = element_text(size = 15),
      axis.text = element_text(size = 12)) 
graf2+scale_fill_manual(values=c("#DE2D26", "#4D4D4D","#FB6A4A","black"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach, be careful about what you aggregate and try to integrate in one dataframe all variables:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Load data
dados4 <- read.csv('DADOSGRAPHBARRA.csv',stringsAsFactors = F,sep=';')

dados4$VARIAVEIS = as.factor(dados4$VARIAVEIS)
dados4$PERIODO = as.factor(dados4$PERIODO)
dados4$GRUPOS  = as.factor(dados4$GRUPOS)
#Compute summaries
errors <- dados4 %>%
  group_by(VARIAVEIS,PERIODO,GRUPOS) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Resposta), 
            sd = sd(Resposta),
            sem = sd(Resposta)/sqrt(length(Resposta)))
gap3 <- aggregate(Resposta ~ VARIAVEIS + PERIODO + GRUPOS, data=dados4, FUN=mean)
#Merge
gap31 <- gap3 %>% left_join(errors)
```

Now, the plot:

```
#Plot
ggplot(gap31, aes(x = VARIAVEIS, y = Resposta, fill = factor(PERIODO))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-1.96*sd,ymax=mean+1.96*sd),position = position_dodge(0.9))+
  facet_grid(~ GRUPOS) + 
  theme(strip.text.x=element_text(size = 15)) +
  labs(title = "",
       x = "Variáveis",
       y = expression(paste('Comprimentos e Diâmetros'," ",'(',mu, m,')')),
       fill = "Períodos") +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 15),legend.text = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", hjust=1),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#DE2D26", "#4D4D4D","#FB6A4A","black"))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Duck! You are also trying to color or graph using the RColorBrewer patch cores, in that for the group CONTROLE the colors will be tons of gray and vermelho more light and for the group IRRADIADOS as colors will be red and gray more dark, still, or code is only inserting as dark colors??

Comment: I think is more dark colors as that palette has that function.